# jQuery .before() re-executing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that is using .before() and the code it is moving has inline javascript which .before() re-executes.  Is there a way to prevent .before() form re-executing javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the element that you're `.before()`ing and strip script tags from it. (untested)

```
$(newHTML).find('script').remove().end().insertBefore(whereToInsert);
```

Comment: yea, I actually tried that and it does work but this issue is part of the jquery ui and not sure if that would mess anything else up.  I may end up doing this.

Comment: I'm almost certain that jQuery UI's methods don't involve inline Javascript, so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Other than moving the javascript out of the HTML that you're relocating, I suppose you could set a flag to `true` after the first execution of the code, which it checks when executing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can detach the script, move the elements around, then reattach (if you still need it). Something like this:

```
var theScript = $('#foo').​​​​​find('script').detach();
var everythingElse = $('#foo'); // everything minus the script(s)
$('#baz').before( everythingElse ); // Document reflow happens
everythingElse.append( theScript ); // now add it back in?
```

Not tested, but maybe worth a shot.